# VBA Code Seems to be stuck at End If

Tags: vba, excel

I want to loop through a column B and delete all the rows with Empty cells in column B but it seems to be getting stuck at the End If part (No error message)

```
Dim lastrow As Long


With ActiveSheet
   lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Dim i As Integer

i = 2
Do While i <= lastrow
    If Range("B" & i) = "" Then
        ws.Rows(i).Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are deleting rows won’t lastrow need to be reduced by one too?

Comment: You see, if you are deleting a row then all others will shift up. So the index stays the same. No?

Comment: When deleting rows, start from the last row and iterate backward.

Comment: ^ that. Or better yet, use `Union` to make a single `Range` object that includes all `ws.Rows(i).EntireRow` ranges you want to delete, and then delete that single union'd `Range` in a single delete operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know how many iterations you'll need before you begin looping, use a `For` loop.

When you encounter a row you want to delete, `Union` it with the other rows you want to delete.

Once you've marked all rows you want to remove, delete them in one single operation.

```
Dim marked As Range
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To lastRow
    If ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value = "" Then
        If marked Is Nothing Then
            Set marked = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i)
        Else
            Set marked = Union(marked, ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i))
        End If
    End If
Next
If Not marked Is Nothing Then marked.EntireRow.Delete
```

This should perform noticeably faster than iterating the rows in reverse and deleting them one by one.

Note:

- `i` is declared `As Long`, because `Integer` will overflow beyond 32,767; a worksheet can have many more rows than that.
- `Range` calls are all explicitly qualified with `ActiveSheet`. Unqualified `Range` calls *implicitly* refer to `ActiveSheet`... unless you're in a worksheet's code-behind, in which case they refer to that worksheet. Better to have code that does what it says, and says what it does.
- Not clear what `ws` meant to be, since it's nowhere in your code and everything is working off `ActiveSheet` anyway (implicitly or explicitly).

Comment: Love your comments and answers :) One question though, wouldn't it be faster if you reverse to `If Not marked Is Nothing` ? since in most iterations that will be the case, instead of check the `If` and then the `Else ?

Comment: @ShaiRado maybe... in any case an `If` check is happening at each iteration regardless. The impact would be rather minor I'd think.